# How do i disable Sequelize syncing?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to connect mysql to my nodejs project. While creating connection to nodejs it automatically creates tables based on models i have defined. I don't want to auto create tables. How do i disable it?

**My DB Configuration**

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, 
config.db.password, {
    host : config.db.host,
    port : config.db.port,
    dialect : config.db.connection
});
```

**My Connection to DB**

```
/* Database Connection */
db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  console.log('Nice! Database looks fine')
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err, "Something went wrong with the Database Update!")
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you should confirm the connection ,

```
db.sequelize
.authenticate()
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

---

`sync()` is generally for when you want to `sync` your modals with database , and you still want to use `sync` , then use it with these options

```
db.sequelize.sync({
    force : false , // To create table if exists , so make it false
    alter : true // To update the table if exists , so make it true
})
```

Comment: awesome i was actually searching for replacement of `sync()` and `authenticate()` works perfectly

Comment: db.sequelize.sync({force: false}) still creates table is exists. I don't know why

Answer (score 3):

Unless I'm missing something... Just don't call `db.sequelize.sync()`?